# Generate and Insert 1 million rows into simple table

Tags: sql-server

**Description:**

I try to insert 1 million rows into empty table on MSSQL 2012 Express. 
Here my script:

```
-- set statistics time off
drop table t1
create table t1 (id int, a text, b text) 
go

-- #1 - 1,000,000 - 30s -> 45s
with ID(number) as
(
    select 1 as number
    union all
    select number + 1
    from ID
    where number < 1000000 + 1
)
insert into t1
    select number, 'a_' + cast (number as varchar), 'b_' + cast (number/2 as varchar)
    from ID  
    option(maxrecursion 0)


-- #2 - 1 million rows => ~140,000 rows = 120s (have to cancel query)
declare @count int
set @count = 0
while @count < 1000000
begin
    set @count = @count + 1
    insert into t1 
        values(@count, 'a_' + cast (@count as varchar), 'b_' + cast (@count/2 as varchar))
end

-- #3 - ~1,300,000 rows - 18s -> 20s  

with temp as 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) as tcount 
    from sys.all_columns a,  sys.all_columns b
    where a.object_id = b.object_id  
) 
insert into t1
    select tcount, 'a_' + cast (tcount as varchar), 'b_' + cast (tcount/2 as varchar) 
    from temp 
go

declare @count int
set @count = 0
while @count < 3
begin
    with temp as (select max(id) + 1 as max_id from t1)
    insert into t1
        select max_id, 'a_' + cast (max_id as varchar), 'b_' + cast (max_id/2 as varchar) 
        from t1, temp 
    set @count = @count + 1
end

-- #4 -- 1,000,000 = 3s -> 4s (have to drop t1 first)
with a(k) as
(
select 1 as k
union all
select k + 1 from a where k < 99 + 1
) , 
t2 as (
select row_number() over(order by x.k) as k
from a x , a y , a z 
) 
select k as id , 'a_' + cast (k as varchar) as a, 'b_' + cast (k/2 as varchar) as b into t1
from t2
```

**Question:**

After researching , I found 4 solutions. Are there any better solution (not using copy data from files) ?

Comment: Don't use "text" field types.  They're horrible for performance and indexes  on those fields cannot be rebuilt "online".  Use a varchar(x) where x is the reasonable maimun size you expect to support.  And  reasonable is not normally > several hundred.

Comment: Thank Max - In PostgreSQL, I often use "text" type , so I thought MS SQL has the same.

Comment: @Luan It supports it too: character varying(n), varchar(n) = variable-length with limit VS text = variable unlimited length. In the context of this question, it doesn't seem that you need unlimited length strings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Itzik Ben-Gan uses [following approach](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/packing-intervals-priorities)
This is probably the fastest way he found and he's quite smart :-)

```
WITH
  L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)), -- 2^1
  L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),       -- 2^2
  L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),       -- 2^4
  L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),       -- 2^8
  L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),       -- 2^16
  L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),       -- 2^32
  Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS k FROM L5)

select k as id , 'a_' + cast (k as varchar) as a, 'b_' + cast (k/2 as varchar) as b into t1
from nums
where k <= 1000000
```

Answer (score 11):

A variation on dnoeth's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130408/1192):

```
WITH Ten(N) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)   
SELECT
    id = IDENTITY(int, 1, 1)
INTO dbo.T1
FROM Ten T10
CROSS JOIN Ten T100
CROSS JOIN Ten T1000
CROSS JOIN Ten T10000
CROSS JOIN Ten T100000
CROSS JOIN Ten T1000000;

ALTER TABLE dbo.T1
ADD a AS CONVERT(varchar(11), id);

ALTER TABLE dbo.T1
ADD b AS CONVERT(varchar(11), id / 2);
```

This avoids storing the values of a and b; their values will be calculated at runtime as necessary. This may be cheating slightly, but it does have advantages:

- No storage space used for columns a and b
- The *id* column is directly typed as *integer* (4 bytes uncompressed); whereas `ROW_NUMBER` returns *bigint* (8 bytes uncompressed).
- The *id* column is assigned the identity property, so it is not updateable.

Alternatively, storing all columns in the table:

```
WITH Ten(N) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)   
SELECT
    id = CONVERT(integer, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T10.N)),
    a = CONVERT(varchar(11), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T10.N)),
    b = CONVERT(varchar(11), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T10.N) / 2)
INTO dbo.T1
FROM Ten T10
CROSS JOIN Ten T100
CROSS JOIN Ten T1000
CROSS JOIN Ten T10000
CROSS JOIN Ten T100000
CROSS JOIN Ten T1000000;
```

Note the conversion to integer on the *id* column, and the use of a specific length on the *varchar* types. See:

[Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) by [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)

Comment: Ah now I understand. _Took me a while_ Create a table `Ten` with 10 items and then produce a Cartesian product by joining the `Ten` CTE with itself  five times. `POWER(10,6) = 1'000'000`.

Answer (score 4):

Method 1: @dnoeth above, insert time: 1077ms - 1180ms (10 times testing)

Method 2: I try to insert using this method, insert time 989ms -> 1132ms
It's simple .

```
select t1.k as id , 'a_' + cast (t1.k as varchar) as a, 'b_' + cast (t1.k/2 as varchar) as b  into t1
from ( 
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) as k 
from sys.all_columns, sys.all_columns a ) t1
where t1.k < 1000001
```

Method 3 : from Paul White's idea, 450ms

```
with x1 as (select top 1000 object_id from sys.all_columns )
SELECT  id = IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) into t1
from x1 a, x1 b
ALTER TABLE dbo.T1 ADD a AS 'a_' + CONVERT(varchar(20),  id);
ALTER TABLE dbo.T1 ADD b AS  'b_' + CONVERT(varchar(20),  id / 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation of dnoeth's answer:

```
WITH
L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)), -- 6^1
L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),       -- 6^2
L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),       -- 6^4
L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),       -- 6^8
Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS k FROM L3)

select k as id , 'a_' + cast (k as varchar) as a, 'b_' + cast (k/2 as varchar) as b into t1
from nums
where k <= 1000000
```

Much more efficient to use 6 as base since 6^8 (1 679 616) is much closer to 1000000 than 2^32 (4 294 967 296)

Comment: Even more efficient, but less convenient, is to use base 32. 32^4 = 1 048 576

Comment: If a closer value is wanted a smaller modification could be done only on line of `L5`: `L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),       -- 2^20` .