# Recent degradation/variability of HashBytes performance

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database, hashing

Up until a few days ago, T-SQL code we have running in SQL Azure that generates an MD5 for temp table values was fast (a few seconds per hundred thousand on a Business Critical Gen 5, 2 VCores DB). Recently we noticed from our logs that on multiple client DBs and in our tests there is tremendous variance leading to frequent timeouts.

Here is sample code shown generating MD5 and also for SHA2 (though MD5 is our production requirement).

```
begin transaction;

/********************************/
-- create temp table
/********************************/
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
  Id int PRIMARY KEY,
  UriValue nvarchar(256),
  Md5Value binary(16)
);

/********************************/
-- generate many records into temp table
-- source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130392/generate-and-insert-1-million-rows-into-simple-table
/********************************/
  WITH
    L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)), -- 2^1
    L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),       -- 2^2
    L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),       -- 2^4
    L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),       -- 2^8
    L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),       -- 2^16
    L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),       -- 2^32
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS k FROM L5
  )
  INSERT INTO #tmp ( Id, UriValue )
  SELECT k as Id, 
         'http://sample.com/' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), NEWID()) as UriValue
  FROM nums
  WHERE k <= 100000


/********************************/
-- test creation of SHA2 value
/********************************/
  DECLARE @dt datetime;   -- timer
  SET @dt = GETUTCDATE();

  UPDATE #tmp
  SET Md5Value = CAST(HashBytes('SHA2_256', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), LOWER(UriValue)) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) as binary(16));
  
  SELECT DATEDIFF(ms, @dt, GETUTCDATE()) AS Sha2ElapsedMs;
  
/********************************/
-- test creation of MD5 value
-- note: our requirement is for a match to http://md5-hash-online.waraxe.us/
/********************************/
  SET @dt = GETUTCDATE();

  UPDATE #tmp
  SET Md5Value = CAST(HashBytes('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), LOWER(UriValue)) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) as binary(16));
  
  SELECT DATEDIFF(ms, @dt, GETUTCDATE()) AS Md5ElapsedMs;
  
rollback transaction;
```

Note the use of `NEWID()` to generate a GUID, so I don't think caching is the issue in our tests.

Here are some test runs (times in seconds):

| Test | SHA2 | MD5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 39 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 34 | 38 |
| 4 | 9 | 9 |

No other processes are running against the DB during these tests. I see spikes in the Azure portal for CPU (90%) and SQL Server Process (99%) that seem to correlate.

Any idea what might have changed here? Or other ideas for how we can get more predictable performance?

The `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8` helps me to tie to http://md5-hash-online.waraxe.us/ (my requirement).

We cannot use SQLCLR because that requires SQL Server Azure Managed Instance. Currently we are on Azure SQL Database.

I get slightly better performance without cast/convert/collate. But it's within reason (and I need those adjustments to match my spec). I've never had a problem generating millions either... until one week ago (with no other changes and same data and across multiple Azure BizCritical DBs) and now variance is very high.

Here is the [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan/?id=HkqYY1udu). Odd that SQL Server Management Studio shows the 'Compute Scalar Cost' as 0%.

Comment: Related: [What is a scalable way to simulate HASHBYTES using a SQL CLR scalar function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/228789/32281)